# Deploying shiny app over web without using any server ( like shiny server, shinnyapps.io)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

Currently, I have developed a shiny app which works fine on my system and runs on localhost:6000,
Now I want it to be available over the web.
So I am planning to run my app over a virtual machine using AWS, GCP or any cloud service provider and I will mask the port to some web URL.
But I suspect that it won't work as I am not using the [shiny-server](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server).
Will It work?
If Not, then are there any alternatives?

Comment: Have a look at this post https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: As I said that I won't want to use shiny-server

Comment: U have to deploy it somewhere it needs a box

Comment: On Windows, you could have a look at [RInno](https://ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno)